# Does Jenkins Remote API support running all jobs inside a view?

Tags: python, shell, jenkins, remoteapi

I am trying to automate the execution of our Jenkins builds by calling the Remote API from inside a Python or shell script.

When we release software, we create a new "view" inside Jenkins (e.g., `2012-12-02-oursoftware-release`) and then we create build jobs inside this view. It would be nice to write a Python or shell script that took the name of this view in as an argument, and then used the Remote API to just execute all the jobs configured for that particular view.

Is this possible, and if so, how? Thanks in advance.

Comment: how about looping though the list of your `n` jobs and executing this `/jenkins/job/myjob[n]/build?delay=0sec`

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the [Config Slice Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Configuration+Slicing+Plugin)